# What does [URL]() mean?

Tags: swift

I’m working through some Swift code, and have the following statement:

```swift
var files = [URL]()
```

I’m trying to work out what this notation means. I don’t even know what to call it, so I can’t search for it properly.

I understand that `[something]` is an array type and the `()` suggests a function call, but I don’t understand what the combination means. In the rest of the code, I have the line:

```swift
files.append(fileURL)
```

so presumably the syntax constructs an array.

Can anybody explain the syntax?

Comment: `[URL]` if the type of an array that holds `URL`s.  The `()` calls `.init` to construct an empty array of that type.

Comment: see also: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/init()

Comment: FWIW, another common way of expressing `var files = [URL]()` is `var files: [URL] = []`. They are equivalent. Both create an empty array that can contain `URL` objects. See https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/collectiontypes#Arrays

Comment: @Rob `var files: [URL] = []` is what I would normally have written. Is the `var files = [URL]()` more Swifty or just showing off?

Comment: @Rob Thanks. I’ll stick to `var files: [URL] = []` because it feels more intuitive, and harmonises with what I write in other languages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the parentheses mean in this var declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68406836/what-does-the-parentheses-mean-in-this-var-declaration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked:

> I’m working through some Swift code, and have the following statement:
>
> ```swift
> var files = [URL]()
> ```

It is syntax for creating an empty array that can contain `URL` objects. It is equivalent to the syntax shown in [The Swift Programming Language: Collections: Creating an Empty Array](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/collectiontypes/#Creating-an-Empty-Array), which says:

> **Creating an Empty Array**
>
> You can create an empty array of a certain type using initializer syntax:
>
> ```swift
> var someInts: [Int] = []
> print("someInts is of type [Int] with \(someInts.count) items.")
> // Prints "someInts is of type [Int] with 0 items."
> ```
>
> Note that the type of the `someInts` variable is inferred to be `[Int]` from the type of the initializer.

So, the syntax in your question is equivalent to:

```swift
var files: [URL] = []
```

---

As [Alexander said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77897384/1271826) (+1), it is also equivalent to:

```swift
var files = Array<URL>()
```

Or:

```swift
var files = Array<URL>.init()
```

All four variations do the same thing, namely create a empty array that can contain `URL` objects.

Probably needless to say, `[URL]` syntax is considered to be preferable to `Array<URL>`. As [The Swift Programming Language: Collections: Array Type Shorthand Syntax](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/collectiontypes/#Array-Type-Shorthand-Syntax) says:

> **Array Type Shorthand Syntax**
>
> The type of a Swift array is written in full as `Array<Element>`, where `Element` is the type of values the array is allowed to store. You can also write the type of an array in shorthand form as `[Element]`. Although the two forms are functionally identical, the shorthand form is preferred and is used throughout this guide when referring to the type of an array.

In terms of `var files: [URL] = []` vs. `var files = [URL]()`, while the *The Swift Programming Language* uses the former, both are frequently seen and one might describe it merely as a matter of personal preference. My only recommendation is to feel free to pick a pattern that works for you and use it consistently within your codebase.

Answer (score 2):

There's two pieces of syntactic sugar here:

- `[T]` is syntactic sugar for `Array<T>`
- `T()` is sugar for `T.init()`

Combined, this is calling `Array<URL>.init()`, i.e. it's initializing a new empty array, and assigning it to `files`.